# More than one criteria SQL IIF

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
  select studentnr, result, 
            iif(result>= 5.5, 'yes', 'no') as passed
    from grade
```

Gives me

> ```
> | Studentnr | Result  | Passed            |
> |-----------|---------|-------------------|
> | 101       | 6.5     | Yes               |
> ```

But i'm trying to achieve

```
| Studentnr | Result  | Passed            |
|-----------|---------|-------------------|
| 101       | 6.5     | Yes lower than 7  |
| 102       | 8       | Yes higher than 7 |
| 103       | 4.5     | No                |
```

Is there a way to do this with IIF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This **is** possible using nested `IIF` statements.

**Example:**

```
SELECT IIF(a.results > 5.5, 

            --Another IIF if it's higher than 5.5
            IIF(a.results <= 7, 'Yes lower than 7', 'Yes higher than 7'), 

            -- else no.
            'No' ) AS Passed
FROM (
      VALUES (4), (6), (8)
     ) AS a(results);
```

However, I completely agree with @Stefano and @Utsav with regard to this. If you need nested `IIFs` then I'd argue that you may as well use `CASE` statements.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN a.results > 7 THEN 'Yes higher than 7'
            WHEN a.results <= 7 AND a.results >= 5.5 THEN 'Yes lower than 7'
            ELSE 'No'
       END AS Passed
FROM (
      VALUES (4), (6), (8)
     ) AS a(results);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what `IIF` is but you can use `case` to achieve the same.

```
select studentnr, result, 
case when result>= 5.5 then 'Yes' 
    else 'No' 
end as passed,
case when result>= 7 then 'Higher than 7' 
    else 'Lower than 7' 
end as gt_lt_7
from grade
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `case` statement to return a single column

```
select studentnr,
       result, 
       case
           when grade <= 5.5 then 'no'
           when grade between 6 and 7 then 'yes, lower'
           else 'yes, higher'
       end as passed
from grade
```

If you need two separate columns, you can add the `case` to the `if` you wrote

```
select studentnr,
       result, 
       iif(result >= 5.5, 'yes', 'no') as passed,
       case
           when grade <= 5.5 then '-'
           when grade between 6 and 7 then 'lower'
           else 'higher'
       end as hi_lo
from grade
```

Answer (score 0):

```
;WITH cte1(studentnr,result)
As
(
SELECT 101,4.5 Union all
SELECT 102,5.5 Union all
SELECT 103,6.5 Union all
SELECT 104,7.5 Union all
SELECT 105,6.5 Union all
SELECT 106,4.5 Union all
SELECT 107,8.5
)
,cte2 AS (
        SELECT studentnr
            ,Result
            ,CASE 
                WHEN result >= 5.5  THEN 'YES'
                WHEN result <= 4.5  THEN 'NO'
                END As Results
        FROM cte1
        )

SELECT CONCAT('studentnr : ',studentnr) AS studentnr
    ,CONCAT('Result : ',result)AS Result
    ,CASE 
        WHEN Results = 'YES' AND result < 7
                THEN 'Passed: Yes lower than 7'
            WHEN Results = 'YES' AND result > 7
                THEN 'Passed: Yes higher than 7'
        WHEN Results = 'NO'
                THEN 'Passed: NO'
        END AS FinalResult
FROM cte2
```